# Issue in Views present in Storage/Framework/Views: Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-blade

I am facing below error.

```
FatalErrorException in b51e1ab1e287e7418abcd006d993c932 line 10:
syntax error, unexpected ';'
```

When I checked the file contents. It was showing error in below line of code. below error is shown in the following File.

**Storage/Framework/Views/b51e1ab1e287e7418abcd006d993c932**

```
<script src=<?php echo e(URL::asset("js/ion_range/ion.rangeSlider.min.js"); ?>></script>
```

Where as when I see the Original View file in resource Folder...It is like below.

```
<script src={{URL::asset("js/ion_range/ion.rangeSlider.min.js"}}></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are missing `)` before closing `}}`

Compare:

```
<script src={{URL::asset("js/ion_range/ion.rangeSlider.min.js")}}></script>
```

with your:

```
<script src={{URL::asset("js/ion_range/ion.rangeSlider.min.js"}}></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the codes provided, you are missing a closing bracket ).